# AUCTeX XeLaTeX preview fails: fontspec cannot-use-pdftex error

Tags: xetex, auctex, preview

I am struggling setting up AUCTeX preview in a way that I can use it with XeLaTeX documents. When I try to generate the previews I get the following error

> ```
> cannot-use-pdftex
> ```

generated by the `fontspec` package. So I guess I have to force the use of XeLaTeX even when generating previews, but I didn't find anything suitable on the net.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,BCOR=8mm,DIV=calc,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{url}
\newcommand{\nacr}{\newacronym}

\title{Some title}
\author{}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{equation}
\theta=asdf_{bsdf}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

and here is the full result:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
! 
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
! 
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
! instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

...

```
Preview-LaTeX exited as expected with code 1 at Sun Apr 01 09:30:59
LaTeX: LaTeX found no preview images
```

Setting local variables didn't help.

If I remove:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
```

The error is gone.

In consequence, I guess I need a way to force auctex to compile previews with xelatex.

Any ideas or existing setups?

Some additional information: AUCTeX 11.86 and gs 9.0 on debian wheezy as well as AUCTeX 11.86 on windows 7.

preview of `circ.tex` works fine

Comment: As you are using `preview`, you need a `.dvi` file. LuaLaTeX can generate these, XeLaTeX cannot. (No idea on _how_ to force the use of `dvilualatex`, I'm afraid.)

Comment: you have to run xelatex with `xelatex -no-pdf`, but this generates an extended `dvi` which can only be converted into a pdf with `xdvipdfmx`

Comment: OK, looks like I have ot understand a little bit more about what happens within preview.  Does 'xelatex -no-pdf' create the preview images during a normal run? Or does the preview run only use the dvi file? Are the preview images only created during the 'C-c C-p'? Then 'xelatex -no-pdf' shouldn't help really, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XeTeX does not generate `.dvi` files. Instead, it creates an 'extended `.dvi` (`.xdv`) file, which is usually converted straight to PDF format by `xdvipdfmx`. You can interrupt the process at the `.xdv` stage using `xelatex -no-pdf`, but that will not help with `preview`, as the latter requires a `.dvi` files. As such, the only way to work with `preview` and `fontspec` is to use LuaLaTeX in `.dvi` mode, using `dvilualatex`. (I'm not sure how to set that as the engine for AUCTeX, but that would be a separate question!)